# SwiftUI view not updating inside List View

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new in swiftUI development. And I had a very weird bug which was that ForEach inside a List is not updated after Published Object is updated.

It is something like this

```
import SwiftUI

struct MaterialsView: View {
    @StateObject private var materialVM = MaterialViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            switch materialVM.state{
            case .success(let materials):
              //here if wrap with List, nothing will display
              //List {
                ForEach(materials, id: \.id){ mat in
                    Text(mat.name)
                }
                //}
            case .loading:
                ProgressView()
            case .failure:
                Text("Something went wrong")
            }
        }
        .task{
            await materialVM.getMaterials()
        }
    }
}
```

```
@MainActor
class MaterialViewModel : ObservableObject{
    enum State{
        case loading
        case success(data: [Material])
        case failure(error: Error)
    }
    
    @Published private(set) var state: State = .loading

    func getMaterials() async{
        FirestoreService.shared.getMaterials { result in
            switch result{
            case .failure(let err):
                self.state = .failure(error: err)
            case .success(let data):
                self.state = .success(data: data)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct Material : Codable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
}
```

But after I removed outer List, The View can be updated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you attach your code to investigate the issue ? Also for the id. If your object already has an id property, You don't have to add it in the ForEach call. ForEach(list) { item in Text(item.name) }

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Hello Usefz89, I just updated my code, please have a check

Comment: Oh and for the id, it seems like I declared id as String type, so I still need to add it in the ForEach call.